# using object.defineproperty with knockout observables

Tags: object, knockout.js

can i (and if yes how) create a `ko.observable` out of a `object.defineproperty` something like this

```
Strength: ko.observable(
    Object.defineProperty(this, "strength", {
        get: function () {
            return this.level * 2;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
)
```

and

```
<span> str: <span data-bind="text: Strength"></span> / 100 </span>
```

what im trying to do is update the display of `strength` when its called after every level-up

i.e.

1. level up
2. (fight) request the current strength
3. update strength (`+=2`)
4. update strength display

**using `Object.defineProperty`**

i would probably just use `ko.computable`, but im wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: please give a little more context and if possible a jsfiddle example ... if "Strength: ko..." is part of your viewmodel litteral definition, then the value for "this" would be the window object - not sure if thats what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit unclear what you want to achive but I'd go with [ko.computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). If you want the subscribers (namely your span) of your `Strength` property to be notified (when the `level` changes after the initial binding), you should also make `level` observable.

if you still want to use defineProperty, I hope [this little example suits you](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/UFcXW/) (edit: added a button to level up)

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.level=ko.observable(5);
    self.really_use_computed = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.level() * 2;
    });
}

var MyViewModel=new ViewModel();

Object.defineProperty(MyViewModel, "Strength", {
    get: function () {
        return this.level() * 2;
    },
    enumerable: true
});

ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

please note that [Internet Explorer 8 standards mode supports DOM objects but not user-defined objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the first argument of `Object.defineProperty()` and that earlier versions of IE [don't support `Object.defineProperty()`](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) at all.

Comment: "i would probably just use `ko.computable`, but im wondering if there is a way to do it." - srry for being unclear will edit.

Comment: does my example of using definePropery suit you? as far as I can see, it answers your question - defines a Strength property on your model and allows knockout to update your span when the level changes. am I missing anything? :D

Comment: Added a button to my previous example to demonstrate the actual change

Comment: If there is any other way I could improve my answer, let me know. Otherwise be kind enough and mark it accepted, if you find it useful ^^

Comment: Using @JaakKütt's example, I rewrote it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nwayve/JTLfk/ to hide the implementation of KO.  I'm not sure how I feel about this though.  I kind of like it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Knockout ES5 plugin](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5) will do what you need.  Although I had to also include the [Weakmap shim](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/#comment-26699) to make it work.